# Converting table-relations from mdb file to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, ms-access, mdbtools

I want to extract the table relationships and data from mdb file and convert it to JSON. I have tried using external tools like mdb-schema from mdbtools,accessdb  but I am only able to generate the data and not the table relations.

Can someone provide inputs?

Comment: Use VBA and the `DAO.Relation` objects.  Enumerate the relations starting with `db.Relations`.  See [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193195.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you !
Is there some other-way apart from VBA ?

Comment: You should be able to use any development environment (i.e. programming language) that supports COM objects including DAO and Office Automation objects, so technically you don't need to use VBA specifically, but this will definitely be a programming task.  I am not familiar with 3rd party tools that you can use to extract such metadata, especially tools that would then pipe the information into a JSON tool.  (Stack Overflow questions are supposed to focus on programming anyway, not suggestions for 3rd party tools.)  Best of luck.